# Generic Implementation gets "cannot add 'T' to 'T' error

Tags: rust

I'm trying to generic implementation and is trying to add a struct's fields of x and y which are both of type T,

I'm getting a red squiggly line under `impl<T> Point<T>` and also the following error message...

```
cannot add `T` to `T`

no implementation for `T + T`

help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `T`
```

As can be seen from my code, I have already added the trait `std::ops::Add` for type `T`.

How do I get the code below working?

```
struct Point<T>
where
  T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
{
  x: T,
  y: T,
}

impl Point<f32> {
  fn add_f32(&self) -> f32 {
    self.x + self.y
  }
}

//error
impl<T> Point<T> {
  fn add(&self) -> T
  where
    T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
  {
    self.x + self.y
  }
}
```

Comment: The compiler actually helps you further here: _"help: consider restricting type parameter `T`"_, followed by the line `impl<T: std::ops::Add> Point<T> {`. Once you do this, you will find a few other issues to solve (i.e. `Add` receives its operands by value, yet you have a reference to `&self` and `T` is not constrained to `Copy`.

Comment: Note that this problem occurred because the constraint `T: Add<Output = T>` was placed at the struct declaration. It can also be omitted in this case, because we don't need it here: `struct Point<T> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}`

Comment: you are right. it works after i remove the where clause in the struct defintion and also remove the ampersand in self. i will put in the working code here

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions to this problem, which have different pros and cons.

The first solution is to just remove the `T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>` bound from the struct definition:

```rust
struct Point<T> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}
```

This means that the `add()` method is unavailable for a type `Point<T>`, if `T` doesn't implement `Add`. However, you're still able to create such a type. If you then try to call the `add()` method on it, Rust will show an error – [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd6f59615c8fb80ec8969a747b340366).

The other solution is to keep the trait bound, which means that it must be enforced every time it is used:

```rust
struct Point<T: Add<Output = T>> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}

impl<T: Add<Output = T>> Point<T> {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required
    ...
}
```

This means that a `Point<T>` can only exist if `T` implements `Add`. You can do this if a type `Point<SomeTypeThatIsntAdd>` doesn't make sense at all or is useless. It also improves compiler diagnostics in some cases.

Comment: The second approach is often avoided due to its "viral" effect. Every impl block for that struct would then need to include that trait bound, even if it isn't relevant to the implementation at hand.

Comment: from your code example and base on E_net4... comment, so it seems better practise will be not to add in trait bound on structs and just put in trait bound on implementations instead

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Point<T> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}

impl Point<f32> {
  fn add_f32(&self) -> f32 {
    self.x + self.y
  }
}

impl<T> Point<T> {
  fn add(self) -> T
  where
    T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
  {
    self.x + self.y
  }
}
```